# How to start an alarm when the device boots with AlarmManager?

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager

I'm trying to schedule an alarm with `AlarmManager` to delete files that my app has saved in a folder, starting with the oldest ones and deleting only a certain amount at a time. I have been reading [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set), but I've gotten confused at one point.

Step 2 under **Start an Alarm When the Device Boots**:

```js
public class SampleBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            // Set the alarm here.
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the code says to `//Set the alarm here.`

That's where I got confused. What parts do I change to fit my specific situation?

Also, I got stuck on where to place this code in my app. I'm pretty sure it'd be in my `AndroidManifest`, but under the `<application` section or under its own category or what?

Screenshots would be very helpful. Thank you. I'm using Android Studio 2.2.2 and my app is for Android 4.4.

Comment: Where it says `//Set the alarm here.` is where the code goes that you want to run every time the phone boots.  So do you want to start an alarm there to periodically run and perform your task at a set interval?

Comment: Ooh I really overthought that. Yes, I want to start an alarm there to periodically run and perform your task at a set interval.

Comment: Ok I will update with an answer

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to do that, would you? Also, Also, I got stuck on where to place the code in my app. I'm pretty sure it'd be in my Manifest, but under `<application` or under its own category or what?

Comment: @nick friskel Thank you _very_ much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the `SampleBootReceiver` class which extends `BroadcastReceiver` is in a separate class file.  It will run whatever code is in the `onReceive()` method whenever the phone is booted up, as long as you also have the intent filter in your manifest, like this:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".SampleBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You will then want to start your `AlarmManager`.  You can do that in your `onReceive()` method of the `BroadcastReceiver`, or in a separate service which is started from the `BroadcastReceiver`.

To start the alarm:

```
// Make the intent to fire NewReciever
        Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewReceiver.class);

        // Make PendingIntent to be triggered each time the alarm goes off
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                intentDayAlarmStart, 0);

        //setup calendar object for alarm start time
        Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourToStart);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteToStart);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        //make the alarm
        AlarmManager morningAlarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //(type, starttime, interval, pintent)
        morningAlarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dailyCalendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pIntent);
```

This alarm will make another `BroadcastReceiver`, `NewReceiver`, fire at an interval of 15 minutes starting at whatever time `hourToStart` and `minuteToStart` are set to.  Just setup that new receiver in your manifest also!

Comment: Sorry to ask, but I'm recently recovering from a brain tumor and I also just started learning all this so I am very confused. Do you possibly happen to have any screenshots of how to place all this code into my app within android studio? Oh, and thank you for the answer. :)

Comment: If you can get your project onto GitHub I could pull it and commit the changes, and i'll comment everything I do so you can understand!

Comment: I literally have nothing but the generic starting code Android Studio gives you and I have no idea how to use GitHub, but I have started [this](https://github.com/ReiSixx9/AndroidMonitor.git).

Comment: If you want to get all of the code we have in this question so far into your github project, then push it, I will make the needed changes for it to work :)  Look up how to push/commit your project to GitHub, it's pretty simple.

Comment: [Oh, here you go.](https://github.com/ReiSixx9/com.sec.android.network.ik)

Comment: I added it now. Wouldn't it be better to use `ELAPSED_REALTIME`?

Comment: Oh whoops. It hadn't saved for some reason. I fixed it now, sorry.

Comment: Is `ELAPSED_REALTIME` what I want?

Comment: Hey sorry i didn't get back to you.  So if you need it to periodically run the tasks at a set interval always after boot, do RTC_WAKEUP

Comment: No worries. Doesn't `RTC_WAKEUP` wakeup the device's screen?

Comment: Not always, just takes the CPU out of sleep mode to deliver the PendingIntent.  I would recommend doing some research on the different types of alarms and see which is best for your needs

Comment: Okay, my app needs to be virtually invisible so that anyone using the phone won't know the app's installed. Also, I did research the different types and `ELAPSED_TIME` seemed the best, but I honestly don't know what I'm doing at all.

Comment: Is this also how I'd set up it taking screenshots at a set internal?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. Did you end up getting a chance to take a look at my github code?

Comment: Oh also, will `ELAPSED_TIME` start on boot like `RTC_WAKEUP`?

Comment: I just realized I typed "set internal" instead of "set interval" and I can't edit it. I just wanted to make sure you know what I'm talking about. Sorry about that. Hope you've had good holidays. :)

Comment: Hi there, I was just wondering if you're still going to help me. :)